# Java inputstream/outputstream write to file with same name

Tags: java, xml, file, inputstream, outputstream

I have some code that goes through a file tree and adds roots to xml files that don't have them. My problem is when I try to write from the inputstream to an output stream. I'd like to REPLACE the current xml file with the updated version (the one with the root added). I think there's a problem occurring if I make the outputstream the same file as the inputstream. Intuitively it seems to make sense that that'd be a problem. If not, let me know.

How can I remedy this? How can I essentially "update" the xml file, in effect overwriting the other one? I've looked at other answers on here but haven't gotten far.

```
private static void addRootHelper(File root){
    FileInputStream fis;
    List<InputStream> streams;
    InputStream is;
    OutputStream os;

    File[] directoryListing = root.listFiles();
    if (directoryListing != null) {
        for (File child : directoryListing) {
            addRootHelper(child);
        }
    }
    else {
        try{
            // Add root to input stream and create output stream
            fis = new FileInputStream(root);
            streams = Arrays.asList(new ByteArrayInputStream("<root>".getBytes()),fis, new ByteArrayInputStream("</root>".getBytes()));
            is = new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(streams));
            os = new FileOutputStream(root.getAbsolutePath());

            // Write from is -> os
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            // Read from is to buffer
            while((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) !=-1){
                os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            is.close();
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            System.out.println("Added root to " + root.getName());

        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how would expect to be able to read from a file while simultaneously writing over it? what you can do though is write the output to a different, temporary file. then delete the original file and rename the temporary file to the name of the original. or if the file is small enough, load the whole file into memory, or process entirely in memory, close the file, then write back to it.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it'd be a problem. I considered your solution but was wondering if there was a more elegant way. If not, that certainly works too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd prefer not to use the popular temporary-file approach, then you can always just read in the whole file, then write back to it afterwards.

Here's a straight-forward implementation.

```
public static void addRootTag(File xml) throws IOException {
    final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();;
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(xml)) {
        while (in.hasNextLine())
            lines.add(in.nextLine());
    }

    try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(xml)) {
        out.println("<root>");
        for (String line : lines) {
            // indentation, if you want
            out.print("    ");
            out.println(line);
        }
        out.println("</root>");
    }
}
```